# How do I use the KeyListener interface?

Tags: java, listener, keypress, keylistener, keyevent

I am just starting to use the `KeyListener` interface. I want to create a very simple console application. I would like the program to print "hi" if I ever press the key 'ENTER'. Unfortunately, due to my lack of knowledge, when I press the enter/return key on my keyboard, nothing happens. I am not using the Scanner class because it requires the user to type something in and or just hit enter to execute something. I would like a process to continue until it is interrupted by a key press. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Trash implements KeyListener {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
      System.out.println("hi");
      switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
         case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
            System.out.println("hi");
      }
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

   public static void main (String [] args){
      Trash obj1 = new Trash();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A KeyListener can only be added to a GUI component. It can't be used in a console application. That's why it's in a `java.awt` subpackage. AWT = Abstract Window Toolkit, the basic GUI toolkit of Java.

If you want to interrupt a "process" when enter is pressed in the console, you should use a thread for your process, and another thread which reads from standard input and interrupts the other one when something is entered.

Comment: Read the Java tutorial about concurrency, and espacially the following page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: Thank you but how do I tie the interruption to a button press?

Comment: `System.in.read(); processingThread.interrupt();` `System.in.read()` blocks until Enter has been pressed in the console.

Comment: It seems like System.in.read() only checks if the user inputs something once, I would like method that will continuously check or can be called multiple times.